# How to checkout latest git tag matching version number

Tags: git

`git checkout tags/0.1.1` will checkout the FIRST commit tagged with that version, as far as I can tell. How can I programmatically checkout the most recent commit tagged with version `0.1.1`? I have made several commits with the same version number, and if I type `git describe --tags` on `master`, I get `0.1.1-3-g18562f7`. I can execute `git checkout tags/0.1.1-3-g18562f7` to get there, but I don't know how to list tags in granular detail so as to be able to find such an automatically generated tag; `git tag`, `git show-ref --tags`, etc only show user-defined tags, e.g.

```
(base) elsphim-4176391:dude holmes5$ git tag                                                   
0.0.1
0.1.0
0.1.1
```

I don't know where to find a list of the automatically incremented build tags `git` generates when you don't increment the version number.

Comment: real tags? tags are not _supposed_ to be moving around (though it's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no automatically generated build tags that you would be able to list with a Git command.

When `git describe --tags` on `master` answers with `0.1.1-3-g18562f7`, then that means:

- `master` actually points to commit `18562f7`,
- the nearest tag before that commit is `0.1.1`,
- and the commit graph at `master` has `3` commits more than the graph at tag `0.1.1`.

In your case that probably means you have this history:

```
--o--o--A--B--C       <- branch master
     ^
     |
     tag: 0.1.1
```

You cannot express the names of `A`, `B`, `C` with the tag name alone. You either must use `master~2` for `A`, `master~` for `B` and `master` for `C`, or you already know the commit IDs, then you do not need the tag name (nor the branch name) to address the commits.

Comment: I think the solution to my problem is then to make my own auto-incrementing tags (all commits to this repository happen programmatically).